# Merge picture with video

Tags: python, image, video, opencv, merge

I want to load an image then merge that image with realtime video frame. How can I do this with OpenCV? I would prefer to use Python, but am open to other languages.

My code so far is (frame is video capture):

```
resim = LoadImage('angel.jpg',1)
SetImageROI(frame, (10, 10, resim.width,resim.height))
Add(frame,resim, frame, None)
ResetImageROI(frame)
```

However, this gives the error

```
src1.size() == src2.size() && src1.type() == src2.type() && func != 0
```

Comment: Please specify few more details. Which line shows this error? To use cv.Add, both sources should be of same type and same size.

Comment: Anyway, [the code here](http://pastebin.com/vNRf1X0b) works fine for me. Try it. Not sure that is what you wanted.

Comment: error is for  Add(frame,resim, frame, None)<br>
it code is fine for the pictures but for the video is not fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. Change video and image file:

```
import cv
resim = cv.LoadImage('image.jpg')
capture = cv.CaptureFromFile('video.avi')
while(1):
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.SetImageROI(frame,(100,100,resim.width,resim.height))
    cv.Add(frame,resim,frame)
    cv.ResetImageROI(frame)
    cv.ShowImage('frame',frame)
    if cv.WaitKey(33)==27:
        break
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Please specify what is the error shown while running this code? Also make sure your image size is less than frame size.

Comment: it work for me , big thanks Rahman K !!!!! but i still have question , how to mix it nature?@AbidRahmanK